# Auto deploy .apk to Android Things using gitlab ci scripting

Tags: android-things, android-things-console

I recently started in a project where Android Things is used. 
When I joined the team, I read up on Android Things.
I very much like the Android Things Console and the way it can push updates. 
However, instead of uploading a new version of an apk by clicking around in the webUI of Android Things Console I would prefer uploading a new version to Android Things console by using some scripting (preferably in gitlab CI).

Does anyone here know of a way to do that? 
I can't find anything about this in the Android Things documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can have a look at https://about.gitlab.com/2018/10/24/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/ may help others who are looking the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, there is no API you can use to upload APKs. You will need to do it manually via the Android Things Console. But I do understand how this would be helpful for your workflow.